# scss - media query not detecting width

Tags: html, css, iframe, sass

I have this mediaquery on my iframe:

`@include breakpoint(m)`

that will be called in:

```
@mixin breakpoint($class) {
    @if $class == s {
        @media (max-width: 599px) { @content; }
    }

    @else if $class == m {
        @media (min-width: 768px) { @content; }
    }

    @else if $class == l {
        @media (min-width: 1280px) { @content; }
    }
}
```

[width responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNS52.png)

however, when passing m doesn't work and it will only trigger on l (1280px). if I pass l, nothing happens. why?

i tried to add "screen and" but didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I'm not well-versed in Sass mq's using breakpoints *and* mixins together enough to tell you why yours isn't working, but I think I can build you a version that does work. what's not working could be a few things: I'm honestly not sure if you can have one-character mixins, but I could be pulling that out of my rear-end. I *think* your main problem may be that the s, m, and l variables aren't declared before your mixins, but I could also be wrong there.

Instead of trying to declare everything in one mixin using breakpoint, it might be easier to use multiple variables:

```
$sm: 599px;
$md: 768px;
$lg: 1280px;
```

then we can declare the mixins:

```
@mixin small {
  @media (max-width: #{$sm}) {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin smMd {
  @media (min-width: #{$sm + 1}) and (max-width: #{$md}) {
    @content;
  }
}
@mixin mdLg {
  @media (min-width: #{$md + 1}) and (max-width: #{$lg}) {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin large {
  @media (min-width: #{$lg + 1}) {
    @content;
  }
}
```

If you do want to use breakpoint, you need to declare your variable:

```
$sm: 499px;
$SmMd: 500px 699px;
$MdLg: 700px 999px;
$lg: 1000px;
```

then you can either use those directly in mq's:

```
.class {
  @include breakpoint($SmMd) {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

Or you can go one further like you're doing above and implement those breakpoints into a mixin... and tbh i never go this far. I always just use breakpoints. Everything I'm about to write is entirely based off of this: https://glennmccomb.com/articles/useful-sass-scss-media-query-mixins-for-bootstrap/

```
// declare the breakpoints
$breakpoints: (
  xs: 576px,
  sm: 768px,
  md: 992px,
  lg: 1200px
);

// retrieve the breakpoint variable, then declare which value we're using
$breakpoint: map-get($breakpoints, sm);

// using "respond above" meaning "this will activate if the screen is above a threshold" 
// take note of the difference between $breakpoints <- with S and $breakpoint
@mixin respond-above($breakpoint) {

  // If the breakpoint exists in the map.
  @if map-has-key($breakpoints, $breakpoint) {

    // Get the breakpoint value.
    $breakpoint-value: map-get($breakpoints, $breakpoint);

    // Write the media query.
    @media (min-width: $breakpoint-value) {
      @content;
    }

  // If the breakpoint doesn't exist in the map.
  } @else {

    // Log a warning.
    @warn 'Invalid breakpoint: #{$breakpoint}.';
  }
}

/* you can also use respond-below($breakpoint) or respond-between($lower, $upper)

@mixin respond-between($lower, $upper) {

  // If both the lower and upper breakpoints exist in the map.
  @if map-has-key($breakpoints, $lower) and map-has-key($breakpoints, $upper) {

    // Get the lower and upper breakpoints.
    $lower-breakpoint: map-get($breakpoints, $lower);
    $upper-breakpoint: map-get($breakpoints, $upper);

    // Write the media query.
    @media (min-width: $lower-breakpoint) and (max-width: ($upper-breakpoint - 1)) {
      @content;
    }
  
  // If one or both of the breakpoints don't exist.
  } @else {

    // If lower breakpoint is invalid.
    @if (map-has-key($breakpoints, $lower) == false) {

      // Log a warning.
      @warn 'Your lower breakpoint was invalid: #{$lower}.';
    }

    // If upper breakpoint is invalid.
    @if (map-has-key($breakpoints, $upper) == false) {

      // Log a warning.
      @warn 'Your upper breakpoint was invalid: #{$upper}.';
    }
  }
}
```

Like I said, all of that is copied from the URL above.

I hope it's helpful. Comment back and tell me if any particular area is tripping you up and i'll see if I can do a better job explaining it.

Comment: thanks for your answer! quite enlightening!

Answer (score 0):

apparently it worked with the deprecated `min-device-width`

the problem was in the iframe itself and not in SCSS.

Comment: Ah ok, I would have guessed just having s, m, l plain would be wrong.

I tried a codepen with using strings and it works.